# Find the differential equation that describes all plane curves

Tags: calculus

Find the differential equation that describes all plane curves such that the tangent line at the point $P=(x,y)$ intersects the x-axis 1 unit to the left of the projection of $P$ on the the x-axis.

Wouldn't this just be $y' = x$ ?

Comment: It could be.  How would you show that this curve meets the requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about differential equations for a moment.  Suppose a line with slope $m$ passes through a point $(x_0,y_0)$.  Under what conditions on $m$ does the line also pass through $(x_0-1,0)$?

The line has equation 
$$
    y-y_0 = m(x-x_0)
$$
If $(x_0-1,0)$ is also on the line, then
$$
    0 - y_0 = m((x_0-1)-x_0) = m(-1)
$$
Therefore $m=y_0$.

Now back to the original question.  If the tangent line to the curve at $(x,y)$ intersects the $x$-axis at $(x-1,0)$, then apparently $\frac{dy}{dx} = y$.